# Deriving the sine Fourier Transform pair with generalized functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am reading through my textbook, and there is a derivation of the $$\sin(2\pi x)\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2i} \delta(\nu -1)-\frac{1}{2i} \delta(\nu+1)$$ transform pair using generalized functions, where $\varphi(x)$ is a test function:

\begin{align*}
\int \mathcal{F} \{\sin(2\pi x)\} \varphi (\nu)\, d\nu &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(2\pi x) \Phi(x)\, dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(x)\frac{1}{2i}e^{i2\pi x}\, dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(x)\frac{1}{2i}e^{-i2\pi x}\, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2i}\varphi(1) - \frac{1}{2i} \varphi(-1).
\end{align*}

Which is then shown to be the Fourier Transform Pair. My question, however, is how they went from:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(x)\frac{1}{2i}e^{i2\pi x}\, dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(x)\frac{1}{2i}e^{-i2\pi x}\, dx
\end{equation}

to
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2i}\varphi(1) - \frac{1}{2i} \varphi(-1)
\end{equation}

As this is not obvious to me.

Comment: I edited your question to make it more readable, in particular I used `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` to line up your equations instead of having several stacked copies of `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`.

Comment: In the last equation, they just used the Fourier transform of the Dirac-mass.

Comment: What is the second part, and which is the last part?  Is this clear?:$ \sin 2\pi x = \frac{1}{2i} (e^{i2\pi x} - e^{-i2\pi x})$

Comment: Is upper-case $\Phi$ meant to be the Fourier transform of lower-case $\varphi$... ?

Comment: Hello, yes the upper-case Φ is meant to be the Fourier transform of lower-case ?